# I get this error when trying to set up a virtual environment using cmd on windows 10

Tags: virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

```
'setprojectdir' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I have activated the environment and was following [this tutorial](https://timmyreilly.azurewebsites.net/python-flask-windows-development-environment-setup/)

Answer (score 0):

`setprojectdir` is a command from virtualenvwrapper. Do you have [virtualenvwrapper-win](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win) installed? Check its bat-files are in the `%PATH%`.